# Minecraft crashing with NVIDIA GPU

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, graphics-card

Hi. Minecraft has only been running with my integrated GPU (Intel UHD Graphics 360), so I got Minecraft to use my external GPU (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060) by going to settings and setting C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft Launcher\runtime\jre-x64\bin\javaw.exe to my "High Performance GPU".

**Screenshot:**
[image]
The problem is that when I try to run Minecraft it crashes with `Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT.`

As far as I can tell I have the latest drivers and updates. It would be very helpful if someone could help me out. I am running Minecraft: Java Edition 1.15.2.

[**Crash Report**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IkcKVpenk_LS_RPl0hGfCze1HokdOrEY)

**Details:**

**Operating System:** Windows 10.0.18363

**Processor:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700 CPU @ 3.00GHz

**Memory:** 32GB

**External GPU Driver:** NVIDIA GeForce Game Ready Driver 442.19

Comment: `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT` is related to incomplete textures. Have you tried reinstalling Minecraft or disabling any texture pack you may be using?

Comment: @Nolonar I'm not using any custom texture pack, just the ones that come with the game. Also what do you mean about reinstalling Minecraft?

Comment: It's possible the game's textures are damaged. Reinstalling Minecraft could solve this problem.

Comment: @Nolonar I've tried reinstalling it and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you sure you reinstalled Minecraft and not just the launcher?

Comment: Xilefian (a Mojang developer) had a similar problem very recently; a recent upgrade of Microsoft's drivers for graphics cards removed support for some old OpenGL feature Minecraft depends on. Make sure to install the driver from Nvidia site.

Comment: Are there different choices of graphics drivers on Windows? I had a very similar problem on Linux, integrated Intel graphics worked, the official NVidia drivers caused lots of problems on my system, but an unofficial one, called "video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-440xx-prime" works. With it, I use the NVidia graphics card by prepending the Minecraft launcher start command with "prime-run ".

Comment: What I found on the bug tracker: 1. Try exiting Discord completely, if you have it, not just the window. Here is a list of other known software that can cause issues: https://minecraftirc.net/support-articles/known-incompatible-software/ 2. Try running Minecraft as administrator. 3. Try a completely new `.minecraft` folder. You could delete your existing one (after backing it up), default location is `%appdata%/.minecraft` on Windows (yes, that is a valid path), or you can point your launcher profile somewhere else. 4. This seems unlikely for you, but just to be sure, you should check the …

Comment: … minimum hardware and software requirements: https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360035131371-Minecraft-Java-Edition-system-requirements-

Comment: @Corsaka Turns out I did just reinstall the launcher. Not the actual game. How would I reinstall ALL of it?

Comment: @SF I installed the driver with the GeForce Experience program. Is that wrong? Should I try installing the same driver from the NVIDIA site? I also have another driver for the Intel GPU. So that might be making Minecraft not work somehow.

Comment: @FabianRöling I do not have discord, but I do have two other programs that may make Minecraft not work, McAfee Anti-virus and GeForce Experience. I wouldn't like to uninstall McAfee Anti-virus but I'm fine with uninstalling GeForce Experience. I still like GeForce Experience though, the site said about how disabling the in-game overlay should solve this issue. How do I disable the in-game overlay? I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: @FabianRöling My CPU is worse than the system requirements by 500MHz.

Comment: The issue I know of was with Microsoft drivers for Nvidia cards, so if you're using ones provided from other sources, it must be a different issue.

Comment: You can reinstall the game itself by clearing the default `.minecraft` folder (the one containing the folder "`versions`"). You should at least temporarily remove or deactivate the program if it's known to be incompatible, because Minecraft might simply not work with it. About the overlay: No idea, Google is your friend. If your CPU is worse than that website says, then the most likely outcome is just lag, but it might also be possible that it simply does not run. I have, however, made Minecraft Java edition run in the past even on a Raspberry Pi, so it should be fine.

Comment: Your crash report lists the Backend API as Intel; potentially related bug track https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-155942?attachmentOrder=desc

Answer (score 1):

What you're encountering is quite weird, as other commenters have said it seems to imply a corrupt texture in the game. (Did you manage to pinpoint when exactly it crashes? Maybe when you look at a specific object in the game?)

Anyways, when dealing with issues of this sort, the answer generally lies in updating this and reinstalling that. (Worst case scenario even reinstalling windows).

So let me walk you through that.

## Step 1: [Reinstall Minecarft](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Minecraft_help_FAQ#Reinstalling_Minecraft)

```
1. Navigate to your Application Data Folder: %AppData%
2. Double Click the .minecraft folder
3. Copy out the saves folder to a different location
4. Go back one directory (to where you can see .minecraft)
5. Drag the .minecraft folder into the trash
6. Start the Minecraft.exe file to re-download Minecraft
7. Close Minecraft when you reach the title screen
8. Copy the saves folder back into the new .minecraft folder. You can safely overwrite any data that's currently in this folder
```

Then try running the game again on your nvidia card, see if it still crashes.

## Step 2: Update things...

If that didn't do the trick, you need to make sure your drivers and Java are both up to date as well.

For your Nvidia drivers, right click your desktop, go to 'Nvidia Control Panel', in there go to 'System Information' (bottom left corner). There you can see your current driver version. (First item under 'details').

Now go to one of Nvidia's driver pages

- https://www.geforce.com/drivers
- https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx

In there select the appropriate graphics card/os combination, and hit search to find the latest graphics driver.

For Java, you can go to this page:

- https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

And download the latest Java JRE and JDK (these will not be the same version!), also for JRE make sure you get both the 32-bit(i586) and 64-bit(x64) versions.

Now you can try running minecraft again, if it didn't work after a full reinstall, it should hopefully work by now.

## Step 3: Fully reinstall your graphic drivers.

If things still aren't working, try doing a full reinstall of your Nvidia drivers, this can get a bit technical so [here's a guide](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/geforce-graphics-cards/5/139267/clean-installation-of-nvidia-graphics-drivers/) for how to do this.

**CLEAN PREVIOUS TRACES**

1. Uninstall any previous drivers through (Add Or Remove Programs).
2. Go to (My Computer > Local Disc > Program files) and delete the "NVIDIA Corporation" folder.
3. Go to (My Comptuer > Local Disc > WINDOWS), then press "CTRL+F" and search for "NV". Delete all the files that start with "NV" or look like they have relevence to Nvidia.
4. Download the latest Nvidia driver from the Nvidia website.
5. Go to (Start > Run > "services.msc"). This will bring up all the services running. Make sure all the services related to drivers are enabled.
6. Complete a registry scan (This will remove any keys that were related with Nvidia, and it could also boost your PC's performance).
   Ccleaner (A free registry cleaner) - http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download/standard

**THE FOLLOWING STEPS WILL NOT ALLOW ACCESS TO THE INTERNET, SAVE THIS TEXT TO REFER TO.**

1. Reboot your computer using safemode by hitting F8 repetably.
   2.Go to (My Computer > Local Disc > WINDOWS), then press "CTRL+F" and search for "NV". Delete all the files that start with "NV" or look like they have relevence to Nvidia.
   (Yes it is the same as step 2 but sometimes the files reduplicate).

**DRIVER INSTALLATION**

3. Open the Nvidia Driver that you downloaded and let it extract the files and folders.
4. Accept the licence agreement.
5. Select "CUSTOM".
6. Install what you need but preferably just the graphics driver so there's less chance of error.
7. Make sure "Clean installation" is checked.
8. Let the installation begin!

Now try minecraft yet again.

## Step 4: Defragment your hard drive/partition

Maybe the cause of your problem is fragmentation of your hard drive/partition (unlikely if you're on an SSD). To defrag your hard drive go to This Pc>Right Click on Local Disk (C:)> Properties> Tools> Optimize

This of course assumes minecraft is installed on your C:\ Drive.

After this, repeat step 1 and try again. There is however a small chance your hard drive might be failing rather than just being sligthly fragmented so download a program (any program that can do it) to check your hard drive health via SMART. (I suggest [CrystaldiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/))

## Step 5: Turn to mods

If it still isn't working, and you're still getting the same error allowing us to assume that you have corrupted textures, then I guess the final option just has to be to download a texture pack to override that corrupted texture (kudos if you can pinpoint the exact texture; then maybe you won't need an entire texture pack).

There are a lot of places where you can get texture packs for minecraft, and I don't feel comfortable recommending any of them because all of them somehow manage to look shady, maybe with the exception of [curseforge](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/texture-packs). Since you like the vanilla textures so much, maybe you would be well served with a texture pack that tries to improve upon the vanilla textures rather than replace them, a great example and personal favorite of mine is called "[Default 3D](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/texture-packs/default-3d-16x)" which creates the illusion of depth (probably using normalmaps...) on the textures.

[Here's how to install a texture pack](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Texture_pack).

1. Download a texture pack. Most texture packs are in ZIP file format, but as long as it has the necessary files (pack.txt), Minecraft recognizes a folder as a texture pack. In-depth instructions on obtaining the files to make custom texture packs are located at Tutorials/Custom texture packs. However this is not necessary, as of snapshot 12w23a, for as long as pack.txt exists, it is recognized as a texture pack.
2. Run Minecraft. If Minecraft is already running, make sure to leave the world.
3. Click Texture Packs in Options.
4. Click Open Texture Pack Folder; this opens the folder where Minecraft stores all texture packs. If nothing happens, the folder must be found manually. Depending on the operating system it is located at:

   - Windows XP and above: %appdata%.minecraft\texturepacks .
   - GNU/Linux: ~/.minecraft/texturepacks (this folder may be hidden in the Home folder).
   - macOS: ~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/texturepacks (this folder may be hidden).
5. Minecraft does not have to be closed when placing the texture pack in the opened folder.
6. In a few seconds the texture pack appears in Minecraft. Select it and click "Done". The texture pack is now applied. If Minecraft did not update, simply exit and reopen the texture packs screen.

If even now after following all the above steps and even trying to replace the problematic textures with a texture pack still hasn't solved the problem, then I'm finally out of ideas.